# Amcharts : How to change the color of the map?

Tags: angular8, amcharts4

I am using amcharts mapchart. I am trying to change the color of the map which is by default grey.

Can someone help me with this?

[Mapchart created with amcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqhBL.png)

Comment: Welcome! This question needs a lot more detail. It would help if you perhaps added some screenshots, a code sample, or much more specific detail to explain what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of a series of mapPolygons use this:

```js
NameOfYourMapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#ffee00")
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work https://codepen.io/NehaSB/pen/LYxMPEL here is my code.

Comment: Here is how I manage the map ;) https://codepen.io/sebastop/pen/ExZJKYJ

Comment: If you accept this answer with the tick button next to it you'll earn few reputation points.